# pytrends_json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: json, python-3.x

I run the following code to get an error:

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
google_username = ''
google_password = ''
pytrend = TrendReq(google_username, google_password, custom_useragent='My Pytrends Script')
pytrend.build_payload(kw_list=['apple', 'sony'], timeframe = 'now 7-d')

pytrend.trending_searches()
```

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

```
pytrend.top_charts(date='201611', cid='apple', geo='US', cat='')
```

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Anyone having similar issues?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like pytrends in pip is out of date. Try to take pytrends from git

```
pip install git+https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends@master --upgrade
```

**UPDATE 1:**

At least they use [different URL for trending searches](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/blob/master/pytrends/request.py#L30).
Source from pip (pytrends/request.py):

```
def trending_searches(self):
    """Request data from Google's Trending Searches section and return a dataframe"""

    # make the request
    req_url = "https://www.google.com/trends/hottrends/hotItems"
```

Source from master branch:

```
TRENDING_SEARCHES_URL = 'https://trends.google.com/trends/hottrends/hotItems'

# some code 

def trending_searches(self):
    """Request data from Google's Trending Searches section and return a dataframe"""

    # make the request
    forms = {'ajax': 1, 'pn': 'p1', 'htd': '', 'htv': 'l'}
    req_json = self._get_data(
        url=TrendReq.TRENDING_SEARCHES_URL,
        method=TrendReq.POST_METHOD,
        data=forms,
    )['trendsByDateList']
    result_df = pd.DataFrame()
```

Comment: The pip version is 9.0.1 and the pytrends version is 4.1.1
Both of them are latest version...

Comment: Thanks for your help!